# HighCharts - problems with tickInterval and tickAmount

Tags: javascript, php, charts, highcharts

I want a fixed y-interval of 5 degrees in my temperature diagram. No multiple of 5. The diagram should decide for itself how many ticks it needs. So tickAmount variable and tickInterval fixed.

However, I only find the opposite case (tickAmount fixed and tickIntervall multiple of 5). 
There is also no maxTickInterval function. How can I help myself?

By the way: I also use opposite: true and linkedTo: 0

Many thanks for your help.
Regards,Chris

Comment: Please add few code snippet to have a better understand better. (what you tried and all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tickPositioner` function to define your own way for tick interval or tick amount, for example:

```
yAxis: {
  tickPositioner: function() {
    var positions = [],
      i = 0,
      min = this.min,
      max = this.max,
      maxTickInterval = 5;

    if (this.tickInterval > maxTickInterval) {
      for (i; i <= max; i += maxTickInterval) {
        positions.push(i);
      }

      return positions;
    }
    // default behavior
    return this.tickPosition;
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4944/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner